# NullReferenceException при запуске игры

Tags: unity3d

```
using UnityEngine;
using DitzeGames.MobileJoystick;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace DitzeGames.MobileJoystick.Example
{
    public class BoxMover : MonoBehaviour {

    protected Joystick Joystick;
    protected Button Button;
    protected TouchField TouchField;
    private CharacterController controller;
    private Vector3 playerVelocity;
    private bool groundedPlayer;
    private float playerSpeed = 2.0f;
    private float jumpHeight = 1.0f;
    private float gravityValue = -9.81f;
    
        
    void Start(){
        controller = gameObject.AddComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

        void Awake ()
    {
        Joystick = FindObjectOfType<Joystick>();
        Button = FindObjectOfType<Button>();
        TouchField = FindObjectOfType<TouchField>();
    }
    

        void Update () {
        
        groundedPlayer = controller.isGrounded; // Пишет что ошибка здесь
        if (groundedPlayer && playerVelocity.y < 0)
        {
            playerVelocity.y = 0f;
        }

        Vector3 move = new Vector3(Joystick.AxisNormalized.x, 0, Joystick.AxisNormalized.y);
        controller.Move(move * Time.deltaTime * playerSpeed);

        if (move != Vector3.zero)
        {
            gameObject.transform.forward = move;
        }


        if (Button.Pressed && groundedPlayer)
        {
            playerVelocity.y += Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -3.0f * gravityValue);
        }

        playerVelocity.y += gravityValue * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(playerVelocity * Time.deltaTime);
        
        //transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + Joystick.AxisNormalized.x * Time.deltaTime * 3f, Button.Pressed ? 1 : 1, transform.position.z + Joystick.AxisNormalized.y * Time.deltaTime * 3f);
    }
}
}
```

У меня есть проблема с тем, что при проверке кода движком, он ошибок не выдаёт, но когда я запускаю код, у меня появляется очень много ошибок с текстом:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
DitzeGames.MobileJoystick.Example.BoxMover.Update () (at Assets/MobileJoystick/Scripts/Example/BoxMover.cs:36)
```

За основу я взял чей-то образец по мобильному джойстику, а код с движением взял с гайда от Unity и пересобрал под джой.
В чём проблема? Помогите решить...

P.S. CharacterController на игроке уже стоит

Comment: Может, Update вызывается до Start?

Comment: Попробовал запихнуть его в Awake, всё тоже самое

Comment: При запуске добавляется компонент CharacterController ? Если вы говорите что уже на игроке, то в старте напишите `controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();`